# Error : Could not connect to database: unable to open database file during package installation

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, r-package

I've written my own package to deal with some stuff related to my work.
The mentioned package contains functions to deal with SQLite connections, PostgreSQL connections and some other useful stuff for me.

I've installed the package (from source) on mac and linux computers, and it works fine. I'm moving my stuff to an EC2 instance on AWS (with ubuntu) for more reliability.

While installing my own package `https:/github.com/jmtruffa/functions` I've come across this:

```
> devtools::install_github("jmtruffa/functions")
Downloading GitHub repo jmtruffa/functions@HEAD
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpCeYT8z/remotesa44439b3f2c/jmtruffa-functions-a5de0d7/DESCRIPTION’
─  preparing ‘functions’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Omitted ‘LazyData’ from DESCRIPTION
─  building ‘functions_0.1.0.tar.gz’

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘functions’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘functions’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘functions’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/functions’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpCeYT8z/filea4440ec4ecf/functions_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Same thing happens if I install from source locally (i.e.: with `install.packages("/path/to/package", repos = NULL, type = "source")`)

Allways installing as root by running: `sudo R`

I'm not quite understanding the meaning of:

```
Error : Could not connect to database:
unable to open database file
```

Since I don't think that the package is ran during installation.

Any hints will be much appreciated.